# Startup applications automatically depending on day of the week

Tags: windows-10, application-launch

Is there any way to automatically startup an application on Windows 10 depending on the day of the week?

For example, I might want to launch Skype on Thursday and Chrome on Friday automatically.

I know you can add apps to startup by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and typing `shell:startup` and pasting application paths into there but I am not aware of a way to customise this depending on the time or day of the week.

Comment: Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler has a lot of options.  Create a new scheduled task ("at system startup" is an option).  I'm not at a Win10 system ATM but I believe it may have day-of-week settings as well.  You may need to look into a shortcut's properties and find the full path of the program to give to Task Scheduler.

Comment: Windows Task scheduler can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, in Windows 10, Task Scheduler can be used to schedule a program by day of week. If  you want to use Task Scheduler to do this and your program doesn't need to start on login the steps would be the following:

> <kbd>Win</kbd>-> type `Task Scheduler`->Action->Create Basic Task ->Fill in Name->`Next`->Weekly->Check day of week->`Next`->Start Program->select `Browse` and select your program->`Next`->`Finish`

However, the OP appears to be asking how to start a program by day of week on login/startup.  Task Scheduler can start a program by day of week OR login but does not appear to allow you to specify both.

To do that you can write a simple VBS script called something like "ExecuteByDayOfWeekOnStartup.vbs" and put it in your Startup folder. To open your startup folder, open the Run window (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>) and type `shell:startup`. This is based on this [microsoft technet answer.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/08/27/how-can-i-determine-the-day-of-the-week/) on determining the day of the week.

Here's a sample vbs script:

```
Dim WshShell 

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

dtmToday = Date()

dtmDayOfWeek = DatePart("w", dtmToday)

Select Case dtmDayOfWeek

    Case 1 'Sunday
    
    WshShell.Run "firefox.exe"
    
    Case 2 'Monday
     
        WshShell.Run "outlook.exe"

        WshShell.Run "msword.exe"

         WshShell.Run "firefox.exe"
    
    Case 3 'Tuesday
    
         WshShell.Run "outlook.exe"

    Case 4 'Wednesday

         WshShell.Run "wednesdayprogram.exe"
    
   Case 5 'Thursday

         WshShell.Run "thursdayprogram.exe"
    
    Case 6 'Friday

         WshShell.Run "fridayprogram.exe"
    
   Case 7 'Saturday
   
         WshShell.Run "saturday.exe"

End Select
```

This is easier than the Task Scheduler as it doesn't require going through the wizard for each task and only requires simple editing of one file. It also allows you to easily specify more than one program to start on each weekday. If the program is not in your system PATH then be sure to add the full path name within the quotes.

Comment: You are a fucking god